# Bit shift operation supported in KDB

Tags: kdb

Can I perform bit shift operations in kdb?
For instance i have a value 256

```
  q)0b vs 256
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000b
```

i would like to multiply by 2 only using bit shift operations:

```
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000b
```

Does kdb support this?
Additionally, is OR supported as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Why was this question downvoted??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `prev` and `next` to shift the bit. For example, to multiply by 2 use `next` then convert back to a number with `0b sv`:

```
0b sv next 0b vs 256
512
```

To shift by more than 1 bit you can use `next` or `prev` with over, or use `xprev`:

```
q)0b sv next/[10;0b vs 256]
262144
q)0b sv -10 xprev 0b vs 256
262144
```

In each case the bit is being shifted 10 places. Note that there is no `xnext`, a negative value must be used with `xprev` instead.

Inclusive OR can be achieved by using `any` or `|` on lists of booleans of equal length, for example:

```
0b sv any 0b vs/:256 512
768
```

Exclusive OR (XOR) can be done with not equals `<>`. In this example there are 3 lists:

```
(<>/)(0011b;0101b;1000b)
1110b
```

Comment: And If I would like to bit shift say 10 times? Should I be using a loop for this?

Comment: You can use the syntax `next/[10;<bits>]` or `-10 xprev <bits>`. I have amended my answer to include an example.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `rotate` [function](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#rotate)

```
q)0b sv   1 rotate 0b vs 256
512j
```

A negative number will move the bits to right i.e. divide by 2:

```
q)0b sv   -1 rotate 0b vs 256
128j
```

**Rotating the bits 10 times**

```
q)0b sv   10 rotate 0b vs 1
1024j
```

**EDIT**: The `rotate` will give funny results if MSB is `1` and rotated left or vice versa. Example :

```
q)1 rotate 1000b
0001b
```

Comment: Rotate will not necessarily give the same output as bit shift, for example `1 rotate 1000b` and `next 1000b` have different outputs.